# changing a list of strings in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to change this list

```
['AAAAA   4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5',
 'BBB     5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2',
 'K       4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1']
```

to something that looks like this

```
AAAAA -- [4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
BBB -- [5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
K -- [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

i have tried multiple ways and cant figure it out

Comment: You can use a dictionary for this: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Please include what you've tried per the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: better use dictionary which will look like `data['AAAAA'] = [4, 2, 1,...]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Are you aware of `str.split` or `re.split`? What have you already tried? What worked and what didn't? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: to get `AAAAA`, `BBB`, `K` you can use `line[:5].strip()` and rest you can `split(' ')` and convert to integers

Comment: How would the output be useful after its processed? Do you want it in a `.json` format?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to split the elements in each string, take the first element and set it as key of the dictionary, and convert the rest of the elements to integers, and store as values:

```
list_ = ['AAAAA   4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5',
 'BBB     5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2',
 'K       4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1']
dict_ = {}
for string in list_:
    alpha, *numbers = string.split()
    dict_[alpha] = [*map(int,numbers)]

for alpha, numbers in dict_.items():
    print(f"{alpha} -- {numbers}")
```

Output:

```
AAAAA -- [4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
BBB -- [5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
K -- [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

If you want to go fancy:

```
generator_ = (f"{alpha} -- {[*map(int,numbers)]}" for alpha, *numbers in [l.split() for l in list_])

print(*generator_, sep = '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reproduce what you asked in the question:

```
x = ['AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5', 'BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2', 'K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1']

for elem in x:
  split = elem.split(" ")
  print("{} -- {}".format(split[0],[int(i) for i in split[1:]]))
```

This:

- Loops through the list `x`
- Splits its items into a separate list `split`
- Separates first element from rest with a "--" when printing

---

Or using a dictionary:

```
x = ['AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5', 'BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2', 'K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1']

# Create dictionary following above logic
d = dict()
for elem in x:
    split = elem.split(" ")
    d.update({split[0] : [int(i) for i in split[1:]]})

# Loop through its keys and values and print as needed
for k, v in d.items():
    print("{} -- {}".format(k, v))
```

## Output:

```
K -- [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1]
AAAAA -- [4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
BBB -- [5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: if OP expects lists with numbers then you would  also need to split `4 2 1 2` and convert to integers.

Answer (score 2):

```
inputlist=['AAAAA   4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5', 'BBB     5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2', 'K       4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1']
for item in inputlist:
  item_to_list=item.split(" ")
  temp_list=[int(i) for i in list(filter(None, item_to_list[2:]))]
  print("{0} -- {1}".format(item_to_list[0],str(temp_list)))
```

Output:

```
AAAAA -- [4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
BBB -- [5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3,2]
K -- [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5', 'BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2', 'K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1']

for i in x:
    i = i.split(' ')
    tmp = {i[0]:[int(items) for items in i[1:]]}
    for i, j in tmp.items():
        print(f"{i} - {j}")
```

Output:

```
AAAAA - [4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
BBB - [5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
K - [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
name=["AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
      "BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
      "K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]


for item in name:
   thelist = list(map(int, ','.join(item.split(' ')[1:]).split(',')))    
   print(f"{item.split(' ')[0]} -- {thelist}")
```

output:

```
AAAAA -- [4,2,1,2,4,2,4,4,5,2,2,1,5,2,4,3,1,1,3,3,5]
BBB -- [5,2,1,2,4,5,4,4,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,3,1,2,3,3,2]
K -- [4,1,2,1,2,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,4,2,2,1,5,1,3,4,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a dict, and also use that dict to get your specific output if that's what you want:

assuming your list is called `full_list`

```
lists = [sub.split() for sub in full_list]
keys = [l[0] for l in lists]
vals = [list(map(int,l[1:])) for l in lists]
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,vals)}
```

if desired to get that specific output:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(f'{k} -- {v}')
```

output:

```
AAAAA -- [4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
BBB -- [5, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]
K -- [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```